# How to Add filter in Elasticsearch-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I Want to add multiple filter with keyword search my code is bellow

```
def search
  return if params[:q].to_s.blank?

  response = Applicant.search(params[:q][:keyword])
  @applicants = response.results
end
```

Here I want to add Last name and city and application date filter. waiting for response. Please Help me anyone. Thanks in advance.